# How do java.exe execute a java source code?

Tags: java, jvm, java-11

When I had only `HelloWorld.java` in the directory without `HelloWorld.class`, `java HelloWorld` in Windows cmd raised a class not found exception. However, `java HelloWorld.java` was executed properly without making `HelloWorld.class`.

From what I understand, JVM reads the bytecodes of a file with .class extension, but fails to read .java file. I understand that java.exe is just a launcher to create JVM and run it, but am now confused how it can work properly with java code, not byte code.

Comment: from the `java` tool [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-source-file-mode-to-launch-single-file-source-code-programs): "If the class identifies an existing file that has a .java extension, or if the --source option is specified, then source-file mode is selected. The source file is then **compiled** and run. ... In source-file mode, the effect is as though the source file is **compiled into memory**," (my emphasis)

Comment: Wrote [an article](https://medium.com/@nigamnaman/introduction-to-java-simplified-56c8b887a799) some time back over the attempt to try out JEP-330 and a brief of what it could possibly mean. Open to feedback to improve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

In modern Java, as a convenience to beginner Java students, the *java* app will graciously compile, and then run, a `.java` file.

Think of it as *java* app detecting a source-code file, then sub-contracting the compilation work out to *javac* app, caching the compiled class in memory, and lastly continuing onwards to run the newly compiled class.

### Details

A [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) comes bundled with a [few dozen tools](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/index.html). A couple of these are crucial:

- [*javac*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/javac.html) — Compiles `.java` file of source code text into `.class` file of bytecode.
- [*java*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) — Execute that `.class` file by launching a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

The process steps are:

1. You write Java source code in a `.java` file, including a `main` method inside a `class` definition.
2. You submit that file to a compiler, such as the *javac* app bundled with every [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit).
3. The compiler outputs a `.class` file.
4. You execute (run) the `main` method by launching the *java* app bundled with every JDK.

You can skip some steps.

- **Compile *and* run a single file:**
  As of Java 11, you can point the *java* app to a `.java` file. The *java* app will automatically compile first, as if *javac* were called on your behalf. Then the *java* app will go on to run the newly compiled class.

  - No `.class` file is written to storage. The compiled class is cached in memory.
  - See [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) for all the details.
  - This behavior is what you noted: *However, `java HelloWorld.java` was executed properly without making HelloWorld.class.*
- **Simplified `main`**
  As a preview feature in Java 21, you can:

  - Write your `java` file without declaring a class. Just write the `main` method alone, with nothing around it.
  - Drop the `public static` from your `main` method declaration.
  - See [*JEP 445: Unnamed Classes and Instance Main Methods (Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445) for details.

#### Motivation

The Java team is making concerted efforts to ease the way for beginning Java programmers, to smooth over the initial speed bumps.  They are trying to mask some of the elaborate ceremony, and make the tooling more friendly and accommodating.

The underlying structures and features of Java are still in place. This is not a “dumbing-down” of Java. These efforts are just attempts at making reasonable accommodations for beginners.

#### *Hello World*

Combining these features, getting started with a *Hello World* app is a simple as writing the following in a `HelloWorld.java` file:

```java
void main() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
```

… and then on the command-line calling:

```bash
java HelloWorld.java
```

Result on the console:

> Hello, World!

That is a vast reduction in labor and confusion for a brand-new student of Java.

---

### *jshell*

By the way… Another piece of making Java easier to use is [*jshell*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jshell.html), a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for Java.

Both beginners and pros find *jshell* handy for running short bits of Java with immediate feedback.

### *BlueJ*

Another useful tool for beginners is [*BlueJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ), an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) designed for students.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [JEP-330](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330), for your example

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

is informally equivalent to

```
javac -d <memory> HelloWorld.java
java -cp <memory> hello.World
```

Comment: equivalent if `hello.World` is the name of the first class found in the `HelloWorld.java` file

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9 we have `jshell` as a REPL tools for Java language (REPL as in Python), an interactive interpreter of Java code source.

Since Java 11, you can either execute JVM bytecode or interpret java source code (source file mode) with the help of the `java` command (see https://openjdk.org/jeps/330). An excerpt of this document is:

> As of JDK 10, the java launcher operates in three modes: launching a
> class file, launching the main class of a JAR file, or launching the
> main class of a module. Here **we add a new, fourth mode: launching a
> class declared in a source file**.

How the interpreter works? That is (almost) of no interest, but highly probable that some compilation steps are made under the hood.